# Perform additional tests before waiting for an event

Tags: python, multithreading

I was looking for a way to perform additional tests before waiting for an event:

```
if everything_is_alright():
    event.wait()
```

But this is not thread-safe. A correct version would be:

```
with lock:
    wait = everything_is_alright() and not even.is_set()
if wait:
    event.wait()
```

The problem is that the lock have to be acquired everytime the event is set/cleared. So I thought about:

```
with event:
    if everything_is_alright():
        event.wait()
```

where `event` has an internal lock that would be released before it actually starts waiting. Since it looks very much like a `Condition`, I sub-classed both `Condition` and `Event` to create this object:

```
from threading import _Condition, _Event    

# Lock Event
class LockEvent(_Condition, _Event):
    """Event that can be locked to perform additional test."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the event."""
        _Condition.__init__(self)
        _Event.__init__(self)

    def wait(self, timeout=None):
        """Wait for the event to be set."""
        with self:
            if not self.is_set():
                _Condition.wait(self, timeout)
            return self.is_set()

    def set(self):
        """Set the event."""
        with self:
            _Event.set(self)
            self.notify()

    def clear(self):
        """Clear the event."""
        with self:
            _Event.clear(self)
```

This is what the documentation says about `_Condition.wait`:

> When the underlying lock is an RLock, it is not released using its release() method, since this may not actually unlock the lock when it was acquired multiple times recursively. Instead, an internal interface of the RLock class is used, which really unlocks it even when it has been recursively acquired  several times. Another internal interface is then used to restore the recursion level when the lock is reacquired.

So far the code is working properly, but:

- am I missing a race condition?
- is there a simpler solution using the standard `threading` objects?